# Optics - Lateral Displacement vs. Angle of Incident

Tags: optics, lenses

The answer to this question has eluded me for some time now. Though I'm not 100% certain, I feel like the answer should be simple, and that I'm missing something silly.

Suppose a have a singlet lens, and sensor perfectly aligned with the lens's focal plane, and an extremely well collimated and monochromatic ray bundle. The resulting spot should displace upon the sensor when a deviation occurs in the bundle's angle of incident.

What's the relation between the lateral displacement of the spot on the sensor given the deviation angle, and the focal length of the lens?

[image]

Comment: $\delta=f\tan\alpha$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a collimated beam the image is at the rear focal plane. This comes from the equation

$$
\frac{n'}{z'} = \frac{n}{z} + \frac{1}{f} 
$$
where $n$ is the index of refraction of the object space which I assume is $1$ in this case (1 is approximately the index of refraction of air). Similarly $n'$ is the index of refraction of the image space which I will also assume is $1$. $z$ is the distance of the object to the lens, which is $-\infty$ when the light is collimated in object space. Thus
$$ z' = f $$

The red bundle of light is at angle $\alpha$ from the optical axis, so you can use the definition of the $\tan$ function to see that the answer is

$$ \tan ( \alpha ) = \frac{\delta}{f}$$ thus

$$ \delta =f \tan (\alpha)  $$

Comment: I'll add to your answer that the 'silly thing' I was looking for was the fact that the ray bundles are 'red hearings', and to solve this problem, one can just choose to examine the chief rays (which by definition, do not refract), yield the above equation easily, under the assumption that all other ray will refract to converge at the same point (only this time, each with a different refraction).

Comment: Thanks for your nice comment. However all rays refract due to Snell's Law including chief rays only time they don't is very special situation line n' = n or $\theta = 0$.  Be careful with your choice of words, in optics refract means a very specific thing. :)

Comment: Correction: the chief rays refract, but do not deviate :)